# Is my proof of this claim correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Let $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$, then $r\cdot q$ is irrational.

$r\in \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ $\Rightarrow r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $r\notin\mathbb{Q} $

Thus, $r$ is irrational.

Proof through contradiction: let's assume $irrational\cdot rational=rational$

Let $q=\frac { a }{ b } $ such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$ let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\neq0$

$$irrational\cdot rational=rational \Rightarrow r\cdot \frac { a }{ b } =\frac { m }{ n } $$

$$(\frac { b }{ a } )\frac { a }{ b } \cdot r=\frac { m }{ n } (\frac { b }{ a } )$$

$r=\frac { mb }{ na } \Rightarrow $ $r$ must be rational since $mb$ and $na$ are integers.

This leads to a contradiction in our assumption. This means our assumption must be false. So, an $irrational\cdot rational$ must be irrational.

Is my proof any good? If not, how can I fix it or improve it?

Comment: Fine except you have to handle $q=0$  separately, otherwise you're forming by $\frac b 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is $99\%$ correct.

One correction is that your proof does not cover the possibility that $a=0$. In fact, your original statement is **FALSE** if $q=0$, so I assume you meant to say that $q$ can be anything *except* $0$.

Just a minor cosmetic correction, I would not use as many repetitions of the word "rational".

I would say:

> Let's assume that there is some rational number and some irrational number such that they multiply to a
>   rational number. Then $$x\cdot q = p$$ where $x$ is irrational, and
>   $p,q$ are rational. Because $p,q$ are rational, there exist
>   $a,b,m,n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $b,n\neq 0$ and $p=\frac ab$ and $q=\frac mn$.

Then, continue with your proof as-is.

---

For most mathematitians, this will be easier to read since we don't like full words in equations. Also, it's nice to use a disticntly different symbol for an irrational number (i.e., call the rationals $p,q,r,\dots$, but call the irrationals $x,y,z,\dots$). This is just convention, but it improves readability.

Comment: Hmm. I think I did too much work then. The directions state "Prove, or disprove using a counter example the following claim:". Obviously if $q$ is $0$, that is a valid counter example. Right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Well, to provide a counter example, you also need to provide an irrational number. But that's easy, since any one will do.

Comment: So my answer is wrong, since there can be a $q$ that disproves this claim. Correct?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Correct.

Comment: If $q=0$ and $r=\sqrt { 2 } $, $r\cdot q=0$ which is rational. Is this good?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Indeed. It is the proof of the statement "There exist such $q,x$ such that $x$ is irrational, $q$ is rational and $r\cdot q$ is rational", which is the negation of the statement you wanted to prove or disprove

Comment: Where is the $x$ coming from in relation to the claim I stated?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I meant to write $r$, sorry.

Comment: So, my final statement should be:

Therefore, there exists such $q,r$ such that $r$ is irrational, $q$ is rational and $r\cdot q$ is rational. 

Correct?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, you should probably handle the possibility that $a=0$ separately.